# how to find only java files in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use CTRL + SHIFT + N shortcut in Intellij to find specific Java files but it also shows .class files; i need to see only .java files. Is there any solution to exclude .class files from CTRL + SHIFT + N ?

Comment: Won't CTRL+N do the trick?

Comment: Thanks. CTRL+N is also useful shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the results using the little blue filter icon in the top right of the window:

[image: File Search]

Choose as few or as many as you need.

Comment: Thanks acanby. Is it also possible to exclude a folder like: web-inf/classes?

Comment: Hmmm sorry I can't find a way to do that. You'd have to do a search and choose a custom scope.